# In Fabric (Python Library) how to access IP/hostname in subrouties?

Tags: python, fabric

In fabric python, how to access IP or hostname in the subroutine?  Want to read configuration file "conf/ip_address.conf", read key/values (using ConfigParser) and then run jobs on remote servers.

Developing tool to backup/version control configuration files from large number of hosts. Idea is - store last modified timestamp of configuration files locally. Use that to get files only when they are modified.

thx,

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming you need the IP or hostname of the remote host that a command is currently executing on. [env.host_string](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/execution.html#connections) provides this. You should be able to set up a custom task and run it with [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute) and within the "current host" can be retrieved through [env.host_string](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/execution.html#connections)

Comment: Took a while for me to realize where you get that "env": `from fabric.api import env`